# I want to get EditText value in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have implemented Listview. I can see my string array inputs in the list view. There is one Edittext box now I want to add value in editText Box everytime addbutton is click it should be seen on the listview later on I have to retrieve the whole list or multiple selection list

I am stuck at how to add the edittext value to the string. Below is the code Please tell me why on clicking Addbutton the edittext is not showing up in the list and how it will refresh everytime I add ? ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.multi);

    ListItem=new ArrayList<String>();
    ListItem.add("000");

    ipList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListItem);
    AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add_Button);
    AddItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ListIP.add(getText(R.id.Multi_Add_EditText).toString());


        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,IP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

```
ListIP.add(getText(R.id.Multi_AddIP_EditText).toString());
```

to see the new value in the list.